# How to round time to nearest day?

Tags: java, time

For my program, I need to round a timestamp (in ms) to the nearest day. To round to hours, I simply do this:

```
private static long roundToHour(long time)
{
    //Add 0.5 hours and then cut off everything unnecessary.
    time += 1800000;
    time = time/(3600000);
    return time*3600000;
}
```

But when I try to do a similar thing with the whole day, the code is 2 hours off. Can anyone please tell me why?

```
private static long roundToDay(long time)
{
    time += 43200000;
    time = time/86400000;
    return time*86400000;
}
```

Comment: @Marcus they are doing integer (long) division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The two hour error is due to timezones.**

You can either add the two hour adjustment yourself or you can use a library like [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

If you add the two hour adjustment yourself, you will have to manually account for Daylight Savings Time.  If you use a library, this will be handled for you.  Dates and times have so many rules.  I highly recommend using a library of some sort to handle dates and times within your application.

Comment: Stupid timezones... But thank you, I'll try to do it with Calendar/Joda.

Answer (score -1):

you can just use java.util.Calendar very easily.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(time);

cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

So you can easily figure out what is the nearest day with the results